# SQL find group wise max date wise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find each item location wise stock_actual with maximum date but display all date row

[image]

```
SELECT  
    MAX(date), Item, Location, Stock_Actual 
FROM 
    INV_Movement
WHERE 
    data <= '2020-05-31'
GROUP BY 
    Item, Location, Stock_Actual 
ORDER BY
    Location
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you have to find out that row and then `JOIN`. You can do that using `TOP 1` in `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT  
    im.date,
    im.Item,
    im.Location,
    im.Stock_Actual 
FROM INV_Movement im
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 im1.*
            FROM INV_Movement im1
            WHERE im1.item = im.item AND im1.location = im.location
            ORDER BY im1.date DESC) im1 
WHERE im.date <= '2020-05-31'
AND im.item = im1.item
AND im.location = im1.location
AND im.date = im1.date
```

Note: `date` column seems `datetime` and the comparison is done with `date` in the `where` clause. It may vary the result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I got the answer myself with google search reference.

The answer is

```
SELECT A.data, A.Item, A.location, A.stock_actual
FROM INV_Moviment A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Item, MAX(date) AS DT, Location 
    FROM INV_Movimentos where data <= '2020-05-31' 
    GROUP BY Item, Location
) AS B ON A.Item = B.Item AND A.Date = B.DT
order by Location, Item
```

Comment: It's good that you got an answer by yourself, there are many ways to retrieve the expected results. Mine is also quite similar :) Anyway good job.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution without self-join using RANK:

```
with cte as
 (
    SELECT data, Item, location, stock_actual,
      rank() -- rank per item based on descending date
      over (partition by Item
            order by date desc) as rnk
      FROM INV_Movimentos
      where date <= '2020-05-31' 
 )
select *
from cte 
where rnk = 1
order by Location,Item
```